# Specifying foreach "as" variable as an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I wrote this little script for Cronjobs to expire my users when their yearly sub is up. I'm pulling an associative array with the first query ($results) and then binding to $id for the foreach loop, but it won't run and that's because it's not picking up on the indices specified for $id. How can I specify that $id is an associative array as well so when $results becomes $id my indices are the same?

Thanks

Heres my code

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
include_once '../php/link_auth.php';
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$q = 'SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname, email, elevation FROM `members` WHERE (DATEDIFF(curdate(), members.regdate) > 365)';
$results = $mysqli -> query($q);
$i = 0;
$expired_users = "";
foreach($results->fetch_assoc() as $id){
    if($id['elevation'] != 'admin') {
    $user = $id['id'];
    $qUnsub = "UPDATE `members` SET `payment_status` = 'unsub' WHERE id = '$user'";
    $mysqli -> query($qUnsub);
    $i++;
    $expired_users .= PHP_EOL.'ID: '.$id['id'].PHP_EOL.'Username: '.$id['username'].PHP_EOL.'Name: '.$id['firstname'].' '.$id['lastname'].PHP_EOL.'Email Address: '.$id['email'].PHP_EOL;
    }
}
echo 'Report for expired subscriptions on '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A').PHP_EOL.'Total users unsubbed today: '.$i.PHP_EOL.'Information related to expired accounts:'.PHP_EOL.$expired_users;
exit();
```

Comment: you want a while loop not a foreach

Comment: while( $id = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {, agreed Dagon. foreach needs the full dataset from the start on, while can do this for every iteration.

Comment: Appreciate it guys, my logic seems to have gone out the window tonight. That fixed it right up :)